# When using section* counters don't reset properly. How to fix this?

Tags: sectioning, equations

For example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=3.99      \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \pi^2=9.86    \end{equation}

\section{Two}
\begin{equation} E=mc^2        \end{equation}
\begin{equation} v=\frac{e}{t} \end{equation}

\subsection{Two \& One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=22 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

renders

[image]

vs

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}
\section*{One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=3.99      \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \pi^2=9.86    \end{equation}

\section*{Two}
\begin{equation} E=mc^2        \end{equation}
\begin{equation} v=\frac{e}{t} \end{equation}

\subsection*{Two \& One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=22 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which renders this :

[image]

Comment: How will you reference these equations if you reset the counter but there's no section numbering?  Your example has several `(1)` equations....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just wish to use this for one counter, here `equation`, then you can add the following code to the appropriate sectioning commands

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\cspreto{section}{\setcounter{equation}{-1}\stepcounter{equation}}
\cspreto{subsection}{\setcounter{equation}{-1}\stepcounter{equation}}
```

where `\cspreto` is defined in the `etoolbox` package. This is close to the spirit of the way counters are reset in the LaTeX kernel in recent updates.  If on the other hand you want this to apply to many subcounters then you could use the built in resetting associated to `\refstepcounter`:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr,etoolbox}
\cspreto{section}{\addtocounter{section}{-1}\refstepcounter{section}}
\cspreto{subsection}{\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}\refstepcounter{subsection}}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
```

The reason that the standard `\counterwithin` does not work with `\section*` is that the starred version of the sectioning commend doesn't touch the counter at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\cspreto{section}{\setcounter{equation}{-1}\stepcounter{equation}}
\cspreto{subsection}{\setcounter{equation}{-1}\stepcounter{equation}}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=3.99      \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \pi^2=9.86    \end{equation}

\section*{Two}
\begin{equation} E=mc^2        \end{equation}
\begin{equation} v=\frac{e}{t} \end{equation}

\subsection*{Two \& One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=22 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour in your example is correct. Using

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
```

makes the equation counter into a subcounter of the section counter. However `\section*` doesn't change the section counter, so the equation counter is not reset. It's not too difficult to hack our way around this. The `\stepcounter` command increases the value of a counter by one, and resets all subcounters. From `latex.ltx`, we find that its definition is as follows.

```
\def\stepcounter#1{% 
  \addtocounter{#1}\@ne
  \begingroup
    \let\@elt\@stpelt
    \csname cl@#1\endcsname
  \endgroup}
```

What we need is a macro that performs all the functions of `\stepcounter`, except updating the counter itself. I've called this `\nullstepcounter` in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\makeatletter
\def\nullstepcounter#1{%
  \begingroup
    \let\@elt\@stpelt
    \csname cl@#1\endcsname
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}
\section*{One}
\nullstepcounter{section}
\begin{equation} 2+2=3.99      \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \pi^2=9.86    \end{equation}

\section*{Two}
\nullstepcounter{section}
\begin{equation} E=mc^2        \end{equation}
\begin{equation} v=\frac{e}{t} \end{equation}

\subsection*{Two \& One}
\nullstepcounter{subsection}
\begin{equation} 2+2=22 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\section}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
    \begin{equation} 
        2+2=3.99
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} 
        \pi^2=9.86
    \end{equation}  
\section*{Two}
    \begin{equation} 
        E=mc^2        
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} 
        v=\frac{e}{t} 
    \end{equation}  
\subsection*{Two \& One}
    \begin{equation} 
        2+2=22 
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Which should do all you want.

[image]